# No upload option in App for sharepoint in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to upload web parts into SharePoint online but upload buttons are read-only. A few months back its not readonly.

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/apps/AppCatalog/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Here is the screenshot for the reference[image: axon]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you a Site Collection Admin on the `/apps/` site?

Comment: Yes... I am site collection admin on the apps site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the permission of current user in the “Apps for SharePoint” library.

Go to library settings->”Permissions for this document library” under “Permissions and Management”.

Then you also could switch to another user to check if the same issue will occur.

Updated:

You could access the library settings like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide me the steps to navigate library settings option and how to check the permissions for the app for Sharepoint library in SharePoint online..

Comment: I have updated the reply.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. Library settings are readonly in my case.. I attached screenshot in the main question

Comment: I am afraid that you do not have the enough permission in the “Apps for SharePoint” library.

Comment: I have global admin permissions for sharepoint online.. Is there any other permissions required to access the "APP for sharepoint Library"?

Comment: Even if you have the admin permission for SharePoint online, you do not have the enough permission in the “Apps for SharePoint” library, you still cannot upload solution in the “Apps for SharePoint” library.

Comment: so what kind of permissions required to upload web parts in to "Apps for sharepoint" library?

Comment: Thank you for your help.. When I changed the permission its working...

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could accept it as answer.